# breaking line when it's more than 78 characters between two patterns in bash script

Tags: bash

Me again :)
I need to break line if it is longer than 78 characters (including tab and spaces) and only in case it's between patterns. Input looks like (digits may change):

> --- Pattern1 ---
>   (tab here)2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
>   ...
>   (tab here)2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 . . . 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
>   --- Pattern2 ---

and i need:

> --- Pattern1 ---
>   (tab here)2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 .. (up to 78chars and then)&
>   (rest of previous line goes here,unless it's still more then 78chars, becouse than again)&
>   (and so on and on until the end of the line) .. 2 2
>   next line  also cutted to 78char lines
>   and again
>   --- Pattern2 ---

To achieve this i need to use scripting in bash 2.05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '/PATTERN1/,/PATTERN2/s/.\{78\}/&\n/g' ./infile
```

#### Input

```
$ cat ./infile
fasdflkjsakfsalfjasd
sadf
saf
saf
123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G123456789H123456789I
sadf
sadfasfa
START
123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G123456789H123456789I123456789J123456789K123456789L123456789M123456789123456789N123456789O123456789P
END
asf
sadfas
dfsad
fsad
fsad
```

#### Output

```
$ sed '/START/,/END/s/.\{78\}/&\n/g' ./infile
fasdflkjsakfsalfjasd
sadf
saf
saf
123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G123456789H123456789I
sadf
sadfasfa
START
123456789A123456789B123456789C123456789D123456789E123456789F123456789G12345678
9H123456789I123456789J123456789K123456789L123456789M123456789123456789N1234567
89O123456789P
END
asf
sadfas
dfsad
fsad
fsad
```

#### Edit

If `\n` is not recognized by your version of `sed`. Try the following:

```
$ sed '/START/,/END/s/.\{78\}/&\
/g' ./infile
```

In case that's not clear, after the ampersand, '&', put a backslash to tell the shell you want to do line continuation then press ENTER to insert a literal newline.  Finally, when on the next line, finish up the command with `/g' ./infile`

Comment: my sed don't want to break line with \n. It just insert n like in:`9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1n 1 1 1 1 1 9`

Comment: @kasper See my **Edit** at the end of my answer

Comment: Yeah, after \n refused to work with me i searched and found that trick. The problem is i need it within my script and don't know how to obtain that.

Comment: @kasper it's no different in a script than it is in your shell